# load_csv_with_header() got an unexpected keyword argument 'target_dytpe'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
kospi_training = 'kospi_training.csv'
kospi_test = 'kospi_test.csv'

training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename = kospi_training,
                                                              target_dtype = np.int,
                                                              features_dtype = np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename = kospi_test,
                                                          target_dytpe = np.int,
                                                          features_dtype = np.float32)
```

I created the above code but it does not work. It's giving me this error:

```
TypeError: load_csv_with_header() got an unexpected keyword argument 'target_dytpe'
```

My csv file looks like this:

```
2468,3, x1, x2, x3, label
1085 ,74.45,1.49,1
1082 ,74.66,1.48,1
1081 ,74.59,1.49,0
1082 ,74.04,1.49,1
1077 ,74.02,1.49,0
1070 ,73.48,1.49,0
1067 ,73.68,1.49,1 and so on.
```

I've Googled but I don't know where in my code it goes wrong.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You just have a typo. The argument is `target_dtype` not `target_dytpe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo in your code.

```
target_dytpe = np.int
```

should be:

```
target_dtype = np.int
```

Comment: what is the difference between yours and mine? somehow it works! thanks a lot!

Comment: You had switched the "t" and "y" around in `dtype`. You had spelt it `dytpe`